# Preparing laundry prior to Chatzos on 10 Av

Tags: halacha, clothing, tisha-bav, cleaning

May one sort their laundry and load the washing machine prior to Chatzos (midday) on 10 Av of a year where Tisha B'Av is on a Tuesday, so that, that way, they can immediately turn on the machine at Chatzos?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's a Tuesday? Are you just specifying that to show that it's not Shabbat?

Comment: @Daniel: Well if it was Thursday one may launder clothes earlier due to Shabbos. And if it was Sunday because of it falling out on Shabbos then one may also do it earlier.

Comment: Zerizin makdimin...  :|

Comment: Have you ever heard it's forbidden to do so during the rest of the nine days? (I haven't.) I doubt anything's wrong with it. No source or strong argument, so I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: @msh210 It distracts one from the mourning. Whether that's formally prohibited or not, it's something that could be wrong with it.